# SQL Server DDL Trigger cannot catch DISABLE ALL event

Tags: sql-server, database-trigger

I suddenly realized that I cannot log schema changes caused by events like DISABLE TRIGGER ALL ON tablename;

I have checked this page but could not find a solution: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-events?view=sql-server-ver15

I need to log every statement that alters the database structure, is there any way you can suggest me?

You can easily reproduce this problem by running this sample script:

```
CREATE DATABASE [DDLTEST]
GO
USE DDLTEST
GO
CREATE TRIGGER [TRG_OGUZ_SCHEMALOG]
ON DATABASE FOR
    DDL_DATABASE_LEVEL_EVENTS
AS
    PRINT 'DDL EVENT FIRED !!'
GO
--THIS PRINTS 'DDL EVENT FIRED !!'
CREATE TABLE X(ID INT)
GO
--THIS PRINTS 'DDL EVENT FIRED !!'
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_X ON X AFTER INSERT 
AS
PRINT 'INSERT EVENT !!'
GO
--UNFORTUNATELY THIS DOES NOT PRINT 'DDL EVENT FIRED !!'
DISABLE TRIGGER ALL ON X
```

Comment: There is an [open issue for this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32898904-fire-a-ddl-trigger-when-the-newer-syntax-disable). About the best you can do is upvote that and hope they get round to it (but don't hold your breath). An alternative would be to set up a permanent extended events trace to specifically capture `ENABLE`/`DISABLE TRIGGER` statements, but this would be costly because it needs to filter every single executed statement. There appear to be no separate extended events that fire for this (in particular, `object_altered` doesn't fire).

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
I upvoted it. But it appears we will have to monitor users some other way.